# How to swap 2 integers using pointers?

Tags: c

when I try to swap these two integers using pointers, I get segmentation fault.

Basically before I swap, `x` is assigned to `1` and `y` is assigned to `2`. After I swap `x` is assigned to `2` and `y` is assigned to `1`.

The program takes two integers `x` and `y` and is supposedly meant to swap them:

```
int swap(int x, int y){

    int *swapXtoY;
    int *swapYtoX;

    *swapXtoY = y;
    *swapYtoX = x;
}
```

Comment: `int swap(int x, int y)` method accepts two integer, not two pointer. try following `int swap(int* x, int* y`

Comment: `*swapXtoY = y;` is using an *uninitialised pointer* and this **undefined behaviour** is causing a segfault by writing `y` to somewhere harmful, or out of allowed memory allocation.

Comment: Note that you are missing return;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function `swap` is expecting both of its argument as `int`, but you are passing `int *`. Compiler should raise a warning about this.

It seems that you have no idea how pointers work in C. Your function is just assigning two `int`s to local variables. Function should be like:

```
int swap(int *x, int *y){

    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`swap` method should accept two pointer, instead of two integers.
Try following.

```
int swap(int* x, int* y){
  int temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;    
}
```

Comment: `int * temp` --> `int temp`

Answer (score 1):

You must pass variables by address to functions to change their value.That being said,your functions should expect pointers as well.Here is a generic function that can swap variables of any `C` data type:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Swap(void *x,void *y,size_t bytes);

int main(void)
{
    int x = 3, y = 4;
    Swap(&x,&y,sizeof(int));
    printf("x now : %d\n",x);
    printf("y now : %d\n",y);
    return 0;
}
void Swap(void *x,void *y,size_t bytes)
{
    void *tmp = malloc(bytes);
    memcpy(tmp,x,bytes);
    memcpy(x,y,bytes);
    memcpy(y,tmp,bytes);
    free(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your function passes its arguments *by value*<sup>1</sup>, which makes it impossible for the function to make any lasting changes to them.

Secondly, the *swap idiom* consists of:

- defining an intermediate variable, `temp`, which is initializes to one of the two variables, for example `x`.
- assigning the value of the second variable,`y` to the first <sup>(saved in `temp`)</sup> variable `x` <sup>(now `temp` has value `x` and `x` has value `y`)</sup>.
- finally, assigning `temp`, to the second variable, `y` <sup>(now `x` has the value of `y` and vice versa)</sup>.

In C code, this would look like:

```
void swap (int *x, int *y ) {

    // dereference x to get its value and assign it to temp
    int temp = *x; 

    // dereference x and assign to it the value of y
    *x = *y;

    // complete the swap
    *y = temp;
}
```

Then to call the function:

```
// if the variables are not pointers
swap(&x, &y);

// if variables are passed via pointers
swap(x_ptr, y_ptr);
```

You might want to check the meaning of the [dereference operator *](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) or [address-of operator &](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caaw7h5s.aspx).

---

<sup>1. By value: it passes a copy of the passed variable, which prevents any change outside the function.</sup>